# Which event do I use to log voice channel disconnections

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Which discordjs event would I use to log voice channel disconnections. For example, if I want to create a log for when someone leaves a voice channel, gets disconnected by a moderator from a voice channel, joins a voice channel, etc... Which event would I use? Would I use client.on("voiceStateUpdate") ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 behaviour disconnect . Direct disconnect : user manual disconnect, disconnected by moderator . Changing voice room is the second one

So the code will be

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {
  let newUserChannel = newState.channel;
  let oldUserChannel = oldState.channel;
  if (oldUserChannel === null && newUserChannel !== null) {
      // User Join a voice channel
      // Handle your save when user join in memcache, database , ...
    } else if (oldUserChannel !== null && newUserChannel === null) {
      // User Leave a voice channel
      // Calculate with previous save time to get in voice time
    } else if (
      oldUserChannel !== null &&
      newUserChannel !== null &&
      oldUserChannel.id != newUserChannel.id
    ) {
      // User Switch a voice channel
      // This is bonus if you want to do something futhermore
   }
});
```